# Get detail about coloumn in particular table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

i need to find column details about particular table.This include details about foreign key that table currently using like referenced table name and referenced column name.
currently i used query like this as it is returns whether table contains foreign key or not
but not displaying any info about referenced table name etc.i tried many ways from my side but not getting exact data.here query i tried for reference:
i tried to use **sys.foreign_key_columns** and **sys.foreign_keys** but i got the bugs.may be i am not placing it properly.

```
SELECT  sys.columns.column_id AS ColumnId,sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
sys.types.name AS Datatype,(SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = sys.tables.name AND CONSTRAINT_NAME =(   SELECT  constraint_name FROM 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = sys.tables.name AND constraint_type = 
 'PRIMARY KEY' AND COLUMN_NAME = sys.columns.name ) ) AS IsPrimaryKey, ( SELECT COUNT(column_name)
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE  WHERE TABLE_NAME = sys.tables.name AND CONSTRAINT_NAME 
  = ( SELECT  constraint_name  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = sys.tables.name 
  AND constraint_type = 'Foreign key' AND COLUMN_NAME = sys.columns.name  )  )   AS IsForeignkey,
    sys.columns.max_length  AS Lenght /*BUG*/
     FROM  sys.columns, sys.types, sys.tables WHERE  
    sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id AND sys.types.system_type_id = sys.columns.system_type_id 
    AND sys.types.user_type_id = sys.columns.user_type_id AND sys.tables.name ='tablename' ORDER BY columnid
```

i tried to use **sys.foreign_key_columns** and **sys.foreign_keys** but i got the bugs.may be i am not placing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/) is what you're looking for.